# Reuse %s placeholder without duplicating the variable?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, string-formatting

**mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64)**

I'm running an `INSERT / ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query like this:

```
query = ("INSERT INTO table SET col1 = %s, col2 = %s, col3 = %s ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = %s, col3 = %s")
cursor.execute(insert_post, (var1, var2, var3, var2, var3,))
```

Is there a way to do this without reusing each of the variables in my `cursor.execute()` function, or am I better off doing string formatting with `format()`?

Comment: what database are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use named formatters and pass a `dict` as the second argument.

```
query = ("""INSERT INTO table 
            SET col1 = %(var1)s, 
                col2 = %(var2)s, 
                col3 = %(var3)s 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = %(var2)s, 
                                    col3 = %(var3)s""")
cursor.execute(insert_post, {'var1' : var1, 'var2' : var2, 'var3' : var3})
```

[Reference.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)